# Importing Rasters to ArcSDE 9.3.1 using sderaster

Tags: raster, enterprise-geodatabase, jpg, sderaster

I am trying to import a raster to 11g using the sderaster command.  It is a standalone jpg with a world file associated, and pyramids.

Am I right in assuming I cannot import a JPG, I can only convert to a jpg on the import process i.e. store it as jpg, but not import a jpg?

I am currently lost as importing the jpg file I get an "Error: Invalid input file specified" error.

I know I can do this via sdeexport - sdeimport, but I believe the correct process should be the sderaster -o import process

I am sure we were able to do this with ArcSDE 8.x